# Converting from xlsx to csv in excel changes date data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to convert to csv so that I can plot with R Studio, but when I save as a .csv, the date data changes and I don't mean the format.

For instance, if the date is 2019-05-02 01:30PM in the original document it will convert to 2005-02-19 01:30PM. Changing the format does not help because obviously the year has changed in the data.

Also, this seems to only occur for the first 12 days of each month...

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: *if the date is 2019-05-02 01:30PM in the original document* What value is shown if use number format? `43587.5625`?

Comment: 38402.5625 in the csv file.

Comment: How are you examining the CSV file to tell that the date has changed?  I cannot reproduce your problem if I have a date formatted as you show in Excel; save it as a CSV file, and then examine the CSV file.  I believe you are omitting some relevant steps or other information in your explanation of what you are doing.  The fact it is only occurring for the first 12 days of each month suggests a windows regional date format problem, so include those in your question.

Comment: I don't ask about CSV. I ask about source XLSX.

Comment: 43587.5625 is the value in the xlsx format, Akina

Comment: Ron- This is data exported from a pressure logger in xlsx format. If I export in .csv, or convert the .xlsx to .csv, that is when the problem arises. I thought maybe it was an issue with excel, but it is possible an issue with the raw data of the pressure logger... There are no other steps that I am taking, just simply saving as a .csv. I am examining the csv file simply by clicking on the box with the date, the formula has changed to a different date.

Comment: Raymond.  When addressing a comment to me please type `@RonRosenfeld` so I will be notified. Is it that the pressure logger exports as xlsx, and then you save that xlsx file as a csv file?  Or is there an option for the pressure logger to deliver the data as a csv file?  In either event, I think I'd have to look at the data the the pressure logger is delivering in order to figure out what is going on.  Oh, and to examine csv files, you should examine them using a text editor -- eg: Notepad or Notepad++.  Excel can do funny things when opening a csv file, if not properly instructed.